# ExecutorService is using to do parallel jobs doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using ExecutorService to a simple multithreded application and it contains just two threads, but both of these threads do heavy works. (copying files, mvn packaging a large module)

My intention is to do this both jobs parallely but both of these Threads start together and I observed one thread starts, do some work and again it waits until the another one finished. I can not understand why is this happenining. Hoping an answer from someone. :)

**My code sample:**

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

  Set<Future<Void>> futureSet = new HashSet<Future<Void>>();

  public IX3InstallerThreadPool(List<Callable<Void>> threadList) throws MojoExecutionException
  {
    for (Callable<Void> thread : threadList)
    {
      futureSet.add(executorService.submit(thread));
    }

    execute();
  }

  private void execute() throws MojoExecutionException
  {
    boolean flag = false;
    for (Future<Void> future : futureSet)
    {
      try
      {
        future.get();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Interrupted");
      }
      catch (ExecutionException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown from the thread");
        for (Future<Void> future1 : futureSet)
        {
          future1.cancel(true);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tested your code locally and it seems to work as expected - I gave your thread pool a list of two Callables, each one printing out a different word at one-second intervals. The prints are interleaved just as I would expect them to be from two different threads. Could you clarify more on how this is not performing as you expect?

Comment: The code you execute in the two Callable implementations might not support multi-threading and uses synchronization mechanisms for preventing multi-threaded execution. Therefore you posed the wrong code.

Comment: Yes, I think also. In a one thred it had a command executor using Runtime.getRuntime() and the other one is copying files. Then I changed that to run command using process builder. Then the problem was solved. Still I cannot understand both these methods create seperate porcesses in the execution.